# Linq to SQl partial class not being passed across web service

Tags: wcf, web-services, linq-to-sql

I am using linq to SQL as my ORM and then passing linq To Sql objects across a web service to my aspx UI pages.

This has been working fine when I pass straight up Linq to sql objects across, they get serialised and I am able access them as json. And This webservice also work fine when I pass over poco DTO, as some of the data in these objects come from a few different linq to SQL classes.

The problem I have is when I try and use linq to SQL class with extra fields defined in a custom partial class. The fields in my custom side of the partial class do not get across the web service, The fields in the linq to sql generated side of the partial class do come across.

The fields are there when I create the object and I can see them in the visual studio debugger up until they go across the service, but they are not in the json on the other side.

Here is the partial class

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace GPSO.ATOMWebDataLayer.LinqToSql
{
    public partial class Geofence
    {
        public string FillColor { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Here is the web service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Profile;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Xml;
using GPSO.ATOMWebBusinessLayer;
using GPSO.ATOMWebDataLayer;
using GPSO.ATOMWebDataLayer.LinqToSql;
using GPSO.ATOMWebDataLayer.Objects;
using GPSOnline.ReportWebService;

using Contact = GPSO.ATOMWebDataLayer.LinqToSql.Contact;
using Event = GPSO.ATOMWebBusinessLayer.Event;
using Geofence = GPSO.ATOMWebBusinessLayer.Geofence;

namespace GPSOnline
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "GPSOnline")]
    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class ATOMWebService
    {
        private string _atomDbConnectionString;
        private string _aspNetDbConnectionString;
        private string _satelliteDbConnectionString;

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        public IEnumerable<GPSO.ATOMWebDataLayer.LinqToSql.Geofence> GetAllGeofences()
        {
            NoCache();

            var geofenceRepo = new GeofenceRepository(GetConnectionString());
            return geofenceRepo.GetAllGeofences().ToList();
        }
    }
}

and here is the Repository 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using GPSO.ATOMWebBusinessLayer;
using GPSO.ATOMWebDataLayer.LinqToSql;
using GPSO.MapUtilities;
using GPSO.Repository;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;
using Geofence = GPSO.ATOMWebBusinessLayer.Geofence;

namespace GPSO.ATOMWebDataLayer
{
    public class GeofenceRepository 
    {
        private static string _connectionString = "";

        public GeofenceRepository(string connectionString)           
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }
        public IEnumerable<LinqToSql.Geofence> GetAllGeofences()
        {
            var dataContext = new AtomWebDataContext(_connectionString);
            return allGeofences = dataContext.Geofences.ToList();    
        }
}
```

and here is the ui Page

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Private/ATOMWEB.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    Async="true" Inherits="GPSOnline.Assets" Title="ATOM®web Asset Map" CodeBehind="Assets.aspx.cs" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<%@ Register Src="../UserControls/ucAssetPicker_ClientEvent.ascx" TagName="ucAssetPicker"
    TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderLeft" runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy" runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="/ATOMWEBService.svc" />
        </Services>
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;client=gme-gpsonline" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/MapPanel.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/AssetLabel.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/NumberFormatting.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/DateFormatting.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/Utilities.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/geofences.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/mapUtilities.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = null,
            atomWebServiceProxy = null,
            selectedAssetId = null,
            userPreferences = null,
            userId = null,
            assets = [],
            assetMarkers = [],
            updatedAssets = [],
            assetStatusPanel = null,
            assetContextItem = null,
            trackAsset = false,
            firstTime = true,
            deviceChannels = { },
            assetPanelLayouts = { },
            geoFences = { };

        function contentPageLoad() {
            atomWebServiceProxy = new GPSOnline.ATOMWebService();
        }

        /// <summary>

        /// <summary>        
        /// calls the webservice to get all the geo fences. 
        /// Runs gotGeoFences when service call successfull
        /// </summary>
        function getGeofences() {
           atomWebServiceProxy.GetAllGeofences(gotGeofences);          
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Add the collection of geoFences to the page       
        /// </summary>        
        /// <param name="Result"> A collection of GeoFences </param>  
        function gotGeofences(result) {

            geoFences = new GeoFencesObj(map, result, "chkToggleGeofences", "<%=RadContextMenuGotoGeofence.ClientID%>", !userPreferences.DefaultShowGeofences);

            if (userPreferences.DefaultLocationType == 2 && userPreferences.HomeSiteId != null) {
                geoFences.zoomToGeofence(userPreferences.HomeSiteId);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `[DataMemberAttribute]`:

```
namespace GPSO.ATOMWebDataLayer.LinqToSql
{
    [DataMember]
    public partial class Geofence
    {
        public string FillColor { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, Yeah I tried that. But I get an error on the page. I have attached the screen shoot from firebug.

Comment: Seriously, you couldn't have copied and pasted the text? It's a server error. The server threw an exception that was unhandled. Go look in the Application event log.

Comment: Yeah, no worries, I had a look in the log and there was another field in the partial class, that I left out for brevity that didn't have a setter method. It turns all fields must have both getters and setters.

Comment: For posterity, his error message was "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:52360/ATOMWEBService.svc/jsdebug"